# Use member function in std::packaged_task

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

What I want to do should be quite easy, but I don't get it...

All I want to do is to start a member function of a class in background
at some certain point in time. The result of that function should also be "externally" available. So I want to prepare the task in the constructor (setting the future variable, ... ) and start it at some later point.

I tried to combine std::(packaged_task|async|future) but I didn't get it to work.

This snippet will not compile, but I think it shows what I want to do:

```
class foo {
private:
  // This function shall run in background as a thread
  // when it gets triggered to start at some certain point
  bool do_something() { return true; }

  std::packaged_task<bool()> task;
  std::future<bool> result;

public:
  foo() : 
    task(do_something), // yes, that's wrong, but how to do it right?
    result(task.get_future()) 
  {
    // do some initialization stuff
    .....
  }
  ~foo() {}

  void start() {
    // Start Task as asynchron thread
    std::async as(std::launch::async, task); // Also doesn't work...
  }

  // This function should return the result of do_something
  bool get_result() { return result.get(); }
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `std::async` is a function, not a type

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use [`std::bind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
#include <functional> // For std::bind()

foo() :
    task(std::bind(&foo::do_something, this)),
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    result(task.get_future()) 
{
    //  ...
}
```

Moreover, you are doing the wrong thing here:

```
std::async as(std::launch::async, task)
//         ^^
//         Trying to declare a variable?
```

Since what you want is to call the `std::async()` function, not to declare an object of a (non-existing) type `std::async()`. So as a first step, change this into:

```
std::async(std::launch::async, task)
```

Notice, however, that this will not be enough to get the task running asynchronously: because of the odd behavior of `std::async()` when the returned future is discarded, your task will always be executed *as if* you started it synchronously - the destructor of the returned future object will block until the completion of the operation. (*)

To solve this last problem, you can hold the returned future in your `result` member variable (rather than assigning to `result` the future returned by `std::packaged_task::get_future()` upon construction):

```
    result = std::async(std::launch::async, task);
//  ^^^^^^^^
```

(*) I *think* that MSVC ignores this specification and actually executes the task asynchronously. So if you are working with VS2012, you may not suffer from this problem.

**EDIT:**

[As correctly mentioned by Praetorian in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17286676/1932150), the above would still be problematic, since a copy of the `packaged_task` would be attempted at some point within the implementation of `async()`. To work around this problem, you wrap your `task` object in a reference wrapper by using [`std::ref()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref).

Comment: Great, thanks. That works. But how do I start the task asynchronously? std::async as(std::launch::async, task) still does not work

Comment: @rralf: That is because (1) you are declaring an object, not calling a function, and (2) because of a strange blocking behavior of `async()` when you do not use the returned future. Just do `auto f = async(...)`. See the edited answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it only works with @Praetorian's hint to use std::ref

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that the solution to the last problem will still block once `f` is destroyed.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Can you please explain to me what's the meaning of the `&` here: `task(std::bind(&foo::do_something, this))`? I thought `std::bind` receives a function as first argument, and not an address in memory. Thanks!

Comment: @segfolt: That's how you create a pointer to a member function. Also keep in mind, that you never pass *functions* as arguments, but always pointers. When you do `foo(fxn)`, `fxn` decays automatically to a pointer, so that's the same as doing `foo(&fxn)`

Comment: @AndyProwl: Thanks! I really forgot that `fxn` decays to a pointer. That syntax is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 4):

`do_something()` is a member function, which means it takes an implicit `this` pointer as the first argument. You'll need to [`bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) the `this` pointer, or create a lamda that invokes `do_something`.

```
foo() : 
  task(std::bind(&foo::do_something, this)),
  result(task.get_future()) 
{}
```

or

```
foo() : 
  task([this]{ return do_something(); }),
  result(task.get_future()) 
{}
```

---

```
std::async as(std::launch::async, task);
```

[`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) is a function template, not a type. So the obvious change is

```
std::async(std::launch::async, task);
```

But that causes yet another error because somewhere within the guts of that call a copy of `task` is attempted, but [`std::packaged_task`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/packaged_task) has a deleted copy constructor. You can fix that by using [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref), which will avoid the copy.

```
std::async(std::launch::async, std::ref(task));
```