# Use member function in std::packaged_task with std::thread (not std::async)

Tags: multithreading, c++11, stl, packaged-task

I'm trying to get a std::future from std::thread and it seems that the only way (?) to do so is to use std::packaged_task. Well, in addition, the function I want to call in std::thread is a class member function. I could find this thread [Use member function in std::packaged_task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286458/use-member-function-in-stdpackaged-task) but they use std::async instead of std::thread. I tried to get something compiling based on that post but when I try to compile this code here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>

class test
{
    int fthread(int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    int a;
public:
    test(int a_) : a(a_) {}

    int run(int b)
    {
        std::packaged_task<int(int)>
            task(std::bind(&test::fthread, this));

        //std::thread a(std::move(std::ref(task)), 5, 1);
        std::thread th(std::move(std::ref(task)), b);//<--Edit typo...

        std::future<int> fut = task.get_future();

        return fut.get();
    }
};

int main()
{
    int a = 5, b = 1;
    test t(a);

    int c = t.run(b);

    if (c != (a+b))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error on MSVC 2013:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
class does not define an 'operator()' or a user defined conversion operator to a pointer-to-function or reference-to-function that takes appropriate number of arguments

1>          C:\MesProgs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(1137) : see reference to function template instantiation 'int std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >::_Do_call<_Ty,0x00>(std::tuple<_Ty &>,std::_Arg_idx<0x00>)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          C:\MesProgs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(1137) : see reference to function template instantiation 'int std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >::_Do_call<_Ty,0x00>(std::tuple<_Ty &>,std::_Arg_idx<0x00>)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          C:\MesProgs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xrefwrap(283) : see reference to function template instantiation 'int std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >::operator ()<_Ty>(_Ty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          C:\MesProgs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xrefwrap(283) : see reference to function template instantiation 'int std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >::operator ()<_Ty>(_Ty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          C:\MesProgs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(228) : see reference to function template instantiation '_Ret std::_Callable_obj<std::_Bind<true,_Ret,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >,false>::_ApplyX<_Rx,_Ty>(_Ty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int
1>  ,            _Rx=int
1>  ,            _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          C:\MesProgs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(228) : see reference to function template instantiation '_Ret std::_Callable_obj<std::_Bind<true,_Ret,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >,false>::_ApplyX<_Rx,_Ty>(_Ty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int
1>  ,            _Rx=int
1>  ,            _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          C:\MesProgs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(226) : while compiling class template member function 'int std::_Func_impl<_MyWrapper,_Alloc,_Ret,int>::_Do_call(int &&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<int,int>>
1>  ,            _Ret=int
1>          ]
1>          C:\MesProgs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(495) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Func_impl<_MyWrapper,_Alloc,_Ret,int>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<int,int>>
1>  ,            _Ret=int
1>          ]
1>          C:\MesProgs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(396) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,int>::_Do_alloc<_Myimpl,_Ty,_Alloc>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<int,int>>
1>  ,            _Fty=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>          ]
1>          C:\MesProgs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(396) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,int>::_Do_alloc<_Myimpl,_Ty,_Alloc>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<int,int>>
1>  ,            _Fty=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>          ]
1>          C:\MesProgs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(385) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,int>::_Reset_alloc<_Ty,std::allocator<std::_Func_class<_Ret,int>>>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>  ,            _Fty=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<int,int>>
1>          ]
1>          C:\MesProgs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(385) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,int>::_Reset_alloc<_Ty,std::allocator<std::_Func_class<_Ret,int>>>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>  ,            _Fty=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<int,int>>
1>          ]
1>          C:\MesProgs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(671) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,int>::_Reset<_Ty>(_Fty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>  ,            _Fty=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>          ]
1>          C:\MesProgs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(671) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,int>::_Reset<_Ty>(_Fty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>  ,            _Fty=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>          ]
1>          C:\MesProgs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\future(588) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<_Ret (int)>::function<_Ty>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>  ,            _Fx=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>          ]
1>          C:\MesProgs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\future(588) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<_Ret (int)>::function<_Ty>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>  ,            _Fx=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>          ]
1>          C:\MesProgs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\future(1742) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Packaged_state<_Ret (int)>::_Packaged_state<_Ty>(_Fty2 &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>  ,            _Fty2=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>          ]
1>          C:\MesProgs\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\future(1744) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Packaged_state<_Ret (int)>::_Packaged_state<_Ty>(_Fty2 &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=int
1>  ,            _Ty=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>  ,            _Fty2=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>          ]
1>          main.cpp(51) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::packaged_task<int (int)>::packaged_task<std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >>(_Fty2 &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fty2=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>          ]
1>          main.cpp(51) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::packaged_task<int (int)>::packaged_task<std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >>(_Fty2 &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fty2=std::_Bind<true,int,std::_Pmf_wrap<int (__cdecl test::* )(int),int,test,int>,test *const >
1>          ]
```

I'd appreciate any help! Thank you

Comment: You may also want to look at [`std::promise`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) as a way of using `future`s.

Comment: thank you, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues:

- You don't specify a placeholder for the expected argument in your `bind`. It should be `std::bind(&test::fthread, this, std::placeholders::_1)`, or better yet `[this](int i){ return fthread(i); }`.
- You're trying to move a `reference_wrapper` into `std::thread` when you should be simply moving the `packaged_task` directly: `std::thread a(std::move(task), ...` or passing a `reference_wrapper` by value: `std::thread a(std::ref(task), ....`. If you move the `packaged_task` into the thread, be sure to extract its `future` before moving.
- You pass two arguments - 5 and 1 - into the `std::thread` constructor when the `packaged_task` only takes one argument. From examination of the test in `main`, you want that argument to be `b`: `std::thread a(std::move(task), b);`
- You don't join or detach the thread, so its destructor will call `std::terminate`.

Addressing all of these results in:

```
int run(int b)
{
    std::packaged_task<int(int)>
            task(std::bind(&test::fthread, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    std::future<int> fut = task.get_future();

    std::thread(std::move(task), b).join();

    return fut.get();
}
```

which is semantically identical to:

```
int run(int b)
{
    return std::async(std::launch::async, [this,b]{ return fthread(b); }).get();
}
```

**[Demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/946e9f3c857c9635)**

Comment: Oh man, thank you! The key was the placeholders, I had no clue about it! The two arguments was a typo (I changed the code and forgot to update here, sorry) and the join, for what I read, is not necessary since I'm using future::get() which is able to block the current thread until the work is done. Thank you once again! Cheers, lao

Comment: Actually, I was wrong about calling future::get() without thread::join(), it crashes. By the way, get_future() had to be called before creating the thread, otherwise it will also crash.